# Java: Finding how many times string occurred in a sentence WITHOUT using API

Tags: java, charat

I am supposed to find how many times the word occurred in a given line of a sentence without using API, except .charAt. Any help would be great! thank you

Ex of input:

> dog
>
> My dog is very cute dog
>
> Every dog passes by another dog, dogs will bark at another dog
>
> They are very cute

Ex of a word:

> dog

Final output: 1 in line 1, 2 in line 2, 4 in line 3, 0 in line 4.

I was able to get the howManyTimes output by checking the first letter, but I can't figure out how I can check for ALL of the characters to be the same as the word.

```
public void calculation(String input, String word, int count)
{
    howManyTimes=0;
    line = count + "";
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length() - word.length(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++)
        {
            if(word.charAt(j) == input.charAt(i+j))
            {
                counter++;
                if(word.length()==counter)
                {
                    howManyTimes++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using `length` as well.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3788176)

Comment: Good start. Carry on!

Comment: Lol. Shall we do your homework for you?

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there:

1. condition input.length() - word.length() loses one dog (at the end of line)
2. you have to be careful how you define word (your example does not separate words do "dodog" will include single "dog" word.
3. please zero your counter - or declare inside loop like below:

corrected code:

```
public int calculation(String input, String word)
{
      int howManyTimes = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < input.length() - word.length() + 1; i++)
      {
          int counter = 0;         
          for(int j = 0; j < word.length() && word.charAt(j) == input.charAt(i+j); j++)
          {
              counter++;
          }
          if (word.length() == counter) {
              howManyTimes++;
          }
      }
      return howManyTimes;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried many different logic inside the nested for loops, but it seems like +1 was the only problem.